# Remove duplicate and make multiple rows to single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have data as below in one of my table

```
            ID  SOURCE      TARGET          TEL1                  TELE1    TELE2    
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
            1   TEL         TEL1         5RBTTX4016/8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            1   TEL         TEL1         5RBTTX4018                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            1   TEL         TEL1          5RBTTX4016
```

I would like the data to be distributed across the columns that are blank. I would like the desired output to be like below.

```
            ID  SOURCE      TARGET          TEL1                           TELE1                      TELE2 
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
            1   TEL         TEL1            5RBTTX4016/8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            1   TEL         TELE1                                            5RBTTX4018                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            1   TEL         TELE2                                                                       5RBTTX4016
```

OR

Keeping this in a single like as below will be fine also:

```
            ID  SOURCE      TARGET                         TEL1                        TELE1                      TELE2 
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
            1   TEL         TEL1,TELE1,TELE2            5RBTTX4016/8                5RBTTX4016                    5RBTTX4018
```

IMP -Please note that, As the data will be moved to a different column , the column names will be captured in the "TARGET" column.
I have around 100s of ID like this. ID = 1 is just an example.

I tried:

```
            SELECT id,COALESCE(NULLIF(TEL1,''), TELE3)
            FROM table_name
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if in data Target is line number

```
ID  SOURCE      TARGET               TEL1                  TELE1    TELE2    
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
        1   TEL         TEL1        5RBTTX4016/8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        1   TEL         TELE1       5RBTTX4018                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        1   TEL         TELE2       5RBTTX4016
```

then you can use below query :

```
SELECT
ID,[SOURCE],STRING_AGG([TARGET], ', ') AS [TARGET],
MAX(CASE WHEN [TARGET] = 'TEL1' THEN [TEL1] ELSE NULL END) AS TEL1,
MAX(CASE WHEN [TARGET] = 'TELE1' THEN [TEL1] ELSE NULL END) AS TELE1,
MAX(CASE WHEN [TARGET] = 'TELE2' THEN [TEL1] ELSE NULL END) AS TELE2
FROM
    Mytable
GROUP BY
    ID,[SOURCE]
```